# sql:ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on my first homework assignment and I am having trouble getting it to work properly. The table movie and star work perfectly fine, but when I try to create the table role it gives me this error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

```
create table movie(id integer,
               title varchar(50),
               rating varchar(10),
               genre varchar(15),
               budget integer,
               unique(id,title),
               constraint moviekey primary key(id));

create table star(id integer,
              name varchar(30),
              birth_year integer,
              gender varchar(10),
              salary integer,
              primary key(id,name),
              constraint fk_mov_star foreign key (id) references movie(id) on delete cascade);

create table role(m_id integer,
              s_id integer,
              character_name varchar(40),
              primary key(m_id,s_id,character_name),
              constraint fk_mid_rol foreign key (m_id) references movie(id) on delete cascade,
              constraint fk_sid_rol foreign key (s_id) references star(id));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason: "star(id)" is a foreign key of table star and it actually is referring to "movie(id)".

solution:
set star(id) as primary key; remove the foreign key from star;

```
create table movie(id integer,
               title varchar(50),
               rating varchar(10),
               genre varchar(15),
               budget integer,
               unique(id,title),
               constraint moviekey primary key(id));

create table star(id integer,
              name varchar(30),
              birth_year integer,
              gender varchar(10),
              salary integer,
              primary key(id) );

create table role(m_id integer,
              s_id integer,
              character_name varchar(40),
              primary key(m_id,s_id,character_name),
              constraint fk_mid_rol foreign key (m_id) references movie(id) on delete cascade,
              constraint fk_sid_rol foreign key (s_id) references star(id));
```